# Where is the Windows 7 games icon located?

Tags: windows-7, icons

I've created my own Games folder on my data drive and i'd like to add a picture to the default folder icon:  `Right-Click on Folder > Properties > Customize > Folder Pictures > Choose File...`

I'd like that picture to be the games icon in Windows 7 but I don't know where it is.  I've attached a screen capture of the games icon, but the system version will have an alpha channel and already be on the system, which is better than using this screen capture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in [`C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798922/storage-location-of-yellow-blue-shield-icon).

Comment: thanks oliver.  i had to change the icon rather than choose file for the folder since that option only allowed me to select image files not icon files, but there is a games folder icon in imageres.dll so it worked out great :)

Comment: @Oliver What's the difference between the icon found in `imageres.dll` over `gameux.dll`?

Comment: @iglvzx From what I can tell, they're identical. But I would assume `imageres.dll` is also available if the Games feature in Windows is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is also stored in `%windir%\system32\gameux.dll`

You can find the icon's resource file by doing the following:

1. **Search** for `Games` in the Start Menu

   [image: search]
2. **Right-click** `Games Explorer`

   [image: right-click]
3. **Click** `Change Icon...`

   [image: icon]